# Creating a simple multiselect listview in 2013

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, multi-select

So one of the features I wanted to implement in my app was providing first time users a list of popular topics and requesting they subscribe to 5 or more topics the first time they open the app to make there first experience a little better.

but, when i started searching around for just such a example i was shocked and amazed that the geniuses at Google not only haven't implemented a simple example that achieves this , they have made it extremely difficult for everyone else to do so as well apparently ( im assuming this based on the poor results i received from my searches)

Is there a way to do this in a simple way as of 2013? All I need is a array of the selected list item positions and i can handle it from there.

Comment: Check the ApiDemos, there are examples for multi-select list views.

Comment: yep and no implementation of how to get said selections

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation!

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

And the saving procedure:

```
array = new SparseBooleanArray();
    array = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();

    if (array.size() == 0) {
        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                ListViewCheckBoxed.this);
        adb.setMessage(getString(R.string.lesson_selection))
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    }
                });
        adb.show();
    } else {
        departmentList = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            if (array.valueAt(i)) {
                departmentList.add(listView.getAdapter()
                        .getItem(array.keyAt(i)).toString());
            }

        }
```

}